# How can I access a specific dictionary in JSON file in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

Let's say I have a dictionary in a .json file, created from a Python dictionary and dumped into this file with `json.dump(my_dict, open("file.json", "r"), indent=4)`:

```
{
    "Amazon": {
        "email": "someone@amazon.com",
        "password": "123456",
    }
}
{
    "Stack Overflow": {
        "email": "somebody@stackoverflow.com",
        "password": "password",
    }
}
```

How would I access one of the two dictionaries later in my Python code? There are multiple dictionaries so I can't simply read the .json file to get one and only one dictionary.

I've tried something like assigning the `json.dump()` part to a variable but it still couldn't access a specific dictionary. Basically, the main issue is that I don't have variable-assigned dictionaries or something else to find one particular .json dictionary. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why are there 2 separate JSON dicts in the first place, instead of one with 2 keys ("Amazon" and "Stack Overflow")?

Comment: Also, how did you manage to dump anything into a file using `"r"` mode? Also, trailing commas are invalid in JSON (except JSON5, which is not really widespread yet).

Comment: If you can't fetch data from your data store, the fundamental lesson is that you chose the wrong method of storing your data.  If you need to update this data, perhaps you should be using an SQLite table instead of JSON.

Comment: Sorry, I asked the question with incorrect code and that my problem comes from the faulty example JSON file. Moderators can close this question as needed because I don't really want to delete my own question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update your file to contain a single JSON object, you can access the dictionaries within it using the json.load() function.

```
with open("file.json") as json_file:
items = json.load(json_file)

dict1 = items[0]
```

Comment: Oh yes, I made a mistake there. There should've been only one dictionary in the JSON file. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a JSON file. You have a file that is a concatenation of multiple JSON documents. `json.load` cannot handle this; you have to go lower level with [`JSONDecoder.raw_decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder.raw_decode). This code will load your file into a list:

```
import json

with open('file.json', 'rt') as r:
    raw_json = r.read()

decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
items = []
while raw_json:
    item, pos = decoder.raw_decode(raw_json)
    raw_json = raw_json[pos:].strip()
    items.append(item)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(items)

# => [{'Amazon': {'email': 'someone@amazon.com', 'password': '123456'}},
#     {'Stack Overflow': {'email': 'somebody@stackoverflow.com',
#                         'password': 'password'}}]
```

(assuming the file doesn't actually have trailing commas before closing braces)

Of course, if you only wish to read the `n`-th record, you can stop reading after having read `n` records, instead of accumulating the results in a list.

Note that this is not a standard format. Not all programming languages allow you to JSON-parse a prefix of a string (e.g. in JavaScript you would either have to write a custom parser from scratch, or hack the error message to see where the error occured so you can cut the string off there — neither option is pretty). Use standard formats wherever possible. For example, JSONL (the same format but unindented, with one JSON document per line) is easily parseable in any language because you can predictably cut the raw string into lines before JSON parsing commences, while still being appendable, like your format.